# Changed my code from previous. How to link tableview cells to specfic blog posts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've hardcoded all of the titles of my cells, and am looking to link each individual cell to a different blog post. The section titles are my keys, and the values are an array of the information pertaining to the title. How would I go about this? I'm a bit confused because due to the fact I have sections, the row selected number restarts as I begin the next section. There's some code involving a search bar so disregard that. An example would be so helpful!

```
@interface InfoTableViewController () {
NSDictionary *names;
NSArray *sectionTitles;
}

@end

@implementation InfoTableViewController {
NSArray *items;
NSArray *searchResults;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

names = @{@"Green Manual" : @[@"Basic Rules", @"Pledge Mom Interview", @"Pledge Class Song", @"Code of Conduct", @"History of XXX", @"Founding Sisters of XX", @"Inter-Chapter Council", @"General Facts", @"Crest of XXX", @"Sister of Mine", @"Greek Alphabet", @"Delta Chapter History",@"Actives", @"Associates, Recessives, Retired Actives, Inactives", @"Alumnae", @"Family Tree"],

          @"Interviews" : @[@"Alyson Au", @"Jazzmin Boo", @"Shuki Chan", @"Ivy Cheng", @"Julie Ha", @"Jenny Hong", @"Linde Huang", @"Erica Jon", @"Jenny Lau", @"Jean Lin", @"Vivian Lo", @"Jackie Nguyen", @"Nhi Nguyen", @"Sarah Pham", @"Jasmine Ta", @"Diane Tran", @"Joyce Wong", @"Kathie Wong", @"Jennifer Xu"]};

sectionTitles = [[names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return [sectionTitles count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionNames = [names objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        return [sectionNames count];

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
//static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"         forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionNames = [names objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *name = [sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = name;


NSLog(@"Row selected: %d", indexPath.row);


return cell;
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
searchResults = [items filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                           scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                  objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                 selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to select a cell and detect that in order to move to a different controller, which then would display some of your content.

Even though you have

```
NSLog(@"Row selected: %d", indexPath.row);
```

in your method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
```

That's not the method that actually detects a cell selection. You should use:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

which is a method from TableViewDelegate, and not TableViewDataSource. Your controller needs to implement both. You also need to connect your tableView to your delegate, in this case, your own controller.

Try NSLogging inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath method to track your selection and further push a new controller, or perform a Storyboard Segue.

Comment: Oh yes, I was wondering why my NSLog wasn't giving me the row selected. Thank you for correcting that for me. But I have already put a storyboard segue from my UITableView to another view controller with a UIWebView on top of it, with a push segue and navigation controller. Could you also tell me how I can put all of my values from my section title keys into one single array? I had already declared NSArray *items;

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but from your code it seems you're already getting all your sections into the sectionTitles array.

Comment: Well currently, I have two arrays in my dictionary. How would I combine the two arrays into one array? This would be for my search bar purposes.

Comment: You'd be joining the two arrays. 

NSArray *joined = [array_a arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array_b];

Comment: Lol, I'm so sorry, I'm horrible at explaining objective-c because I'm just starting out. But if you look in my viewdidload method, that's where my data is. 'names' is the dictionary, 'sectiontitles' is my key, and the objects following it are the values. so i guess the objects aren't really an array.. i just need all of the values in a single array so my search bar can go through all of it. i apologize for not being clear enough! oh and ignore the sectiontitles = [[nsarray.. etc] - that was me experimenting.

Comment: You can reach both arrays by doing names[@"Green Manual"] and names[@"Interviews"]. It means that my suggestion might work if you did allItems = [((NSArray *) names[@"Green Manual"]) arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *) names[@"Interviews"]]